# Ошибка при развёртывании проекта

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

[image: скриншот]

ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/mysql:5.7.31

MySQL поставил, не помогло

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: что у вас в Dockerfile, какая у вас система, архитектура процессора?

Comment: Содержимое docker-compose-dev:

version: "3.8"

services:
  php-fpm-a-momenty-org:
    extra_hosts:
      - "ps.ura.news:192.168.1.108"
      - "ps.ura.ru:192.168.1.108"

  nginx-a-momenty-org:
    ports:
      - "192.168.1.108:8888:80"
  nginx-momenty-org:
    ports:
      - "192.168.1.108:80:80"
      - "192.168.1.108:443:443"


Архитектура процессора - ARM, система - macOS Big Sur

Answer (score 0):

Если вы работаете, на Маке с M1 процессором, то по умолчанию Docker пытается скачать образ для arm, но MySql 5.7.31 слишком старый и для arm не существует. Можно попытаться обновить на более актуальную версию или при запуске контейнера/скачивании указать дополнительный параметр `--platform`, например так:

```
docker run --platform linux/amd64 ...
```

Тогда контейнер будет запускатся в эмуляторе QEMU, но работать это будет достаточно медленно и ноут будет греться.